# PyQt: signal emitted twice when calculations are too long

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots, qspinbox

I use two widgets: a `QSpinBox` and a `QLineEdit`. `valueChanged` slot of the `QSpinBox` widget is connected to the `update` function. This function consist of a time-consuming processing (a loop with calculations or a `time.sleep()` call) and  a `QLineEdit.setText()` call. At the beginning, i thought it worked as expected but I noticed that the signal seems to be emitted twice when the calculations takes a long time.

Bellow is the code:

```
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QSpinBox, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # parent constructor
        super().__init__()

        # widgets
        self.spin_box = QSpinBox()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()

        # layout
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        v_layout.addWidget(self.spin_box)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

        # signals-slot connections
        self.spin_box.valueChanged.connect(self.update)

        #
        self.setLayout(v_layout)
        self.show()

    def update(self, param_value):
        print('update')
        # time-consuming part
        time.sleep(0.5) # -> double increment
        #time.sleep(0.4) # -> works normally!
        self.line_edit.setText(str(param_value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another version of `update`:

```
# alternative version, calculations in a loop instead of time.sleep()
# -> same behaviour
def update2(self, param_value):
    print('update2')
    for i in range(2000000): # -> double increment
        x = i**0.5 * i**0.2
    #for i in range(200000): # -> works normally!
    #    x = i**0.5 * i**0.2
    self.line_edit.setText(str(param_value))
```

Comment: I tried same code with same results and that incrementing of param_value? What the hell... I really want to see answer :)

Comment: That's particularly annoying because it works if you just decrease the range argument... Remove one zero and it works.

Comment: I used `time.sleep` instead with lower then `time.sleep(0.4)` it works and with `time.sleep(0.5)` and more it doesnt

Comment: I get the same result. I have never heard of such limitation, i must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real mystery here. If you click a spin-box button, the value will increase by a single step. But if you press and hold down the button, it will increase the values continually. In order to tell the difference between a click and a press/hold, a timer is used. Presumably, the threshold is around half a second. So if you insert a small additional delay, a click may be interpreted as a short press/hold, and so the spin-box will increment by two steps instead of one.

**UPDATE**:

One way to work around this behaviour is by doing the processing in a worker thread, so that the delay is eliminated. The main problem with this is avoiding too much lag between spin-box value changes and line-edit updates. If you press and hold the spin-box button, a large number of signal events could be queued by the worker thread. A simplistic approach would wait until the spin-box button was released before handling all those queued signals - but that would result in a long delay whilst each value was processed separately. A better approach is to compress the events, so that only the most recent signal is handled. This will still be *somewhat* laggy, but if the processing time is not too long, it should result in acceptable behaviour.

Here is a demo that implements this approach:

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QSpinBox, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit,
    )
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QObject, QThread, QMetaObject,
    )

class Worker(QObject):
    valueUpdated = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self._value = None
        self._invoked = False
        self._func = func

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def handleValueChanged(self, value):
        self._value = value
        if not self._invoked:
            self._invoked = True
            QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self, '_process', Qt.QueuedConnection)
            print('invoked')
        else:
            print('received:', value)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def _process(self):
        self._invoked = False
        self.valueUpdated.emit(self._func(self._value))

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.spin_box = QSpinBox()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        v_layout.addWidget(self.spin_box)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.setLayout(v_layout)
        self.thread = QThread(self)
        self.worker = Worker(self.process)
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.valueUpdated.connect(self.update)
        self.spin_box.valueChanged.connect(self.worker.handleValueChanged)
        self.thread.start()
        self.show()

    def process(self, value):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return value

    def update(self, param_value):
        self.line_edit.setText(str(param_value))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```